# Numpy output using OR conditionals differ from output using np.isin

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have an xarray.Dataset such as

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 3259, longitude: 3699, time: 60)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-04-03T10:47:53.500000 ...
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 46.62 46.62 46.62 46.62 46.62 46.62 46.62 ...
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 7.82 7.82 7.82 7.82 7.82 7.821 7.821 ...
Data variables:
    slc        (time, latitude, longitude) uint8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
Attributes:
    crs:      EPSG:4326
```

I can filter it with `mcat = (dataset_in.slc == 9) | (dataset_in.slc == 11)` to get an xarray.DataArray as follows

```
<xarray.DataArray 'slc' (time: 60, latitude: 3259, longitude: 3699)>
array([[[False, False, ..., False, False],
        [False, False, ..., False, False],
        ...,     
       ...
       [[False, False, ..., False, False],
        [False, False, ..., False, False],
        ..., 
        [False, False, ..., False, False],
        [False, False, ..., False, False]]], dtype=bool)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2017-04-03T10:47:53.500000 ...
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 46.62 46.62 46.62 46.62 46.62 46.62 46.62 ...
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 7.82 7.82 7.82 7.82 7.82 7.821 7.821 ...
```

But I would need more flexibility and use instead of the OR conditionals the following code

```
monit_cats = [9,11]
mcat = np.isin(dataset_in.slc, monit_cats)
```

Unfortunately I get a "simple" numpy.ndarray

```
[[[False False False ..., False False False]
  [False False False ..., False False False]
  [False False False ..., False False False]
  ..., 
  ...
  ..., 
  [False False False ..., False False False]
  [False False False ..., False False False]
  [False False False ..., False False False]]]
```

How could I get the exact same first output (in xarray.DataArray format)?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite cleanly with xarray's [`apply_ufunc`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.apply_ufunc.html):

```
monit_cats = [9,11]
mcat = xr.apply_ufunc(np.isin, dataset_in.slc, monit_cats)
```

`mcats` will be an `xarray.DataArray` with the dimensions/coordinates from `dataset_in.slc`.

Comment: Thanks jhamman. Unfortunately  apply_ufunc is available since version 0.10. I have version 0.9.6 installed and cannot update it.